# Destroy the request send to the server in mozilla addon

Tags: sdk, request, firefox-addon, mozilla

I first sent a request to the server from Mozilla Addon SDK , but it takes some time t fetch the data and give the response. In the mean time I would make some other request to the server. Now I have to cancel or destroy the previuos request and my current request has to be processed. How would I destroy the earlier request sent to the server.The type of request which i sent can be referred in the following link.[Mozilla-Addon-SDK-request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/request)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the page you're have linked suggests, advanced usages should import XMLHttpRequest() from the net/xhr module instead, it has an [abort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#abort%28%29) method

Comment: Actually I need the same abort() function in request module.. Could u help me out in this?

Comment: why do you *need* the request module?

Comment: because I need the abort() in main.js not in content-script

Comment: Yes, and my answer does cover that case.